# Need to change the "auto detect" proxy settings in Windows

Tags: windows-7, networking, proxy, malware

I downloaded and accidentally installed some nasty [malware from CNET.com](http://download.cnet.com/9241-2348_4-13811067.html?messageID=10965310). I've finished cleaning up most of it, but there is one setting I haven't been able to get back to normal.

In several programs that connect to the Internet (Firefox, Internet Explorer, Dropbox), there is a Settings -> Network -> Proxies configuration area. It has options like "do not use proxy", "auto detect proxy", and "use this proxy: X.X.X.X". Most of them are set on "auto detect" by default.

One of the malwares I accidentally installed changed whatever that "auto detect" proxy is to 127.0.0.1:XXXX. Now that I deleted the malware, the localhost server is down so that 127.0.0.1:XXXX address is obviously not usable.

Long story short, I need some help figuring out how to change the "auto detect proxy" settings. When you set a program to auto detect the proxy settings, where does it get that proxy from? Is it somewhere in Windows Control Panel?

I'm running Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Auto-detect uses the web proxy autodiscovery protocol, which queries DHCP and a specific URL to try and obtain a proxy autoconfiguration file. If it doesn't get one, it assumes there is no proxy.

You can read about it on Wikipedia ( http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Proxy_Autodiscovery_Protocol)

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question **I need some help figuring out how to change the "auto detect proxy" settings**

Comment: It's possible the virus started intercepting my outgoing connections and spoofed a DHCP server. Maybe these settings do not exist in Windows at all and I am looking in the wrong place. I tried switching a couple programs back to autodetect and I can no longer reproduce the error. So maybe once that spoofed DHCP server went down and I forced a refresh, everything went back to normal.

Comment: The settings are not stored in windows (they may be cached for a bit, I'm not sure)  but a reboot would certainly query for them again.